# Why I can't change Dart-SDK path and version in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio somehow still used Dart-SDK ver. 2.14.4 even though I have downloaded the 2.16.2
I tried changing the path to my latest Dart-SDK in Languanges & Frameworks in Settings.
Then I click apply and run "flutter pub get" but still get this error message

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.4.

I close the Android Studio app, then I open it again.
I run "flutter pub get" and the same error message shows.
I check the Dart-SDK path in Settings and somehow I don't know how the path goes back to 2.14.4 even though I already changed it earlier?

W-w what happens?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flutter SDK contains a Dart SDK that it is designed to work with. Manually setting the Dart SDK is not supported when the Flutter plugin is installed.

just upgrade  your flutter SDK.

Comment: How does one "just upgrade your flutter SDK"?

Comment: Hi @claudekennilol, please take a look at the official documentation about the topic https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/upgrading